# How does Kibbud Av V'Eim work for a child of divorced parents?

Tags: halacha, kibbud-av-veim-honoring, divorce

How does *Kibbud Av V'Eim* work for a child of divorced parents?

(not referring to a case where one tells him to break Shabbos and the other tells him not to)

What about a regular case- like they both ask him to visit for Shabbos. Which parent would get precedence and why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Shulchan Aruch Y.D. 240:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.240.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) rules that if someone's divorced parents both ask him for a favor (the case of the S.A. is requesting a drink), he may choose to respond to either one first.

[Pischei Teshuva s.k. 12](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.240.14?lang=bi&with=Pithei%20Teshuva&lang2=en) suggests that for sustenance and clothing the mother would get precedence.

Comment: That answers it perfectly- thank you so much!

Comment: @alicht You're very welcome. Please also see the qualification in the new paragraph I just added